# Visual Studio 2010 linker error when using boost::thread

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to using the **C++ Boost threading library** in Visual Studio 2010 but get a linker error when including the **thread library** that requires the **boost libs**.

Here is the linker error after including `<boost/thread/thread.hpp>`

> Error 2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class
>   boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl
>   boost::system::generic_category(void)"
>   (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)

After some research I got the impression that this error can be caused by a bad installation or installation of the wrong build version so here is the installation steps I took.

1. Downloaded `boost_1_51_setup.exe` from
   http://www.boostpro.com/download/
2. Ran the installer selecting all the tick boxes on the threading and
   library page
3. Allowed the installer to add an environment variable to the OS path
4. In the visual studio project added `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51`
   to additional dependencies in C/C++-> General
5. Finally added `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_51\lib` to additional
   libraries in Linker->General

I have triple checked all the path, all seem fine. And read the boost getting started page several time... I can't find what I'm missing.

I am running windows 8 x64, although I don't think this makes a difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to link Boost 1.52 thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674374/trying-to-link-boost-1-52-thread)

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project in the solution explorer and click properties.

Go to the VC++ directories tab and add the boost libraries do the 'Library Directories'.

You could also add the include folders to the 'Include Directories' section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this didn't work, the problem isn't with the linker not finding the lib file as it can open it